# Analysis of time period of a complex spring system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

My physics professor tells me the only way to solve for the time period of the give oscillating system

[image]

is by shifting the axis of rotation  to the point of contact of the **CYLINDER** and the surface (**NO SLIPPING)**.

**MY QUESTION**

Can we solve for the time period by assuming 'x' displacement at O and theta rotation at the axis O??

Note:If the problem can be solved this way,please provide a solution with the necessary equations.

Answer (score 0):

Your professor is wrong. There is *always* more than one way to model *any* system correctly. Of course some ways are easier than others.

You are right. You can set up the equation of motion using two variables $x$ and $\theta$ for the translation and rotation of point O. If there is no slipping, you also have the constraint equation that $x = -R\theta$. You can use that to eliminate either $x$ or $\theta$ from the equation of motion (so that makes *two* different ways to solve the problem, as well as the professor's way!) and then find the period of oscillation.

This is not a "do my homework for me" website, so I'm not going to give you a full solution.

Comment: i have already solved this question by my professor's method.The reason for me posting this question here is to understand the alternate method of solving this question which by the way i have tried and failed.This method of solving the question is not necessary for me to learn however i am trying to do so in order to strengthen my concepts.If you could provide a full solution you would not be helping me in my homework in any way.